# How do I count item within an Arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to calculate and print the number of Democrats, Republicans and Independents within a `MemberOfCongress ArrayList`. I already know I need to loop over the list, but, my question is, how do I count up how many of each party type there are?
This is what I got so far.

```
public int countNumDemocrats()
{
    int numDemocrats = 0;
    int numRepblican = 0;
    int numIndepent = 0;
    for (MemberOfCongress MemeberParty : members) {
        if (party.is"D" ) {
            numDemocrats++;
        }
    }
    return numDemocrats;
}
```

Comment: if you use java8 then you can do that using java lambda, otherwise your loop is fine

Comment: you need do the same for Republicans and Independents inside your loop. Also, you need add parameters to return all the 3 numbers. You need be fair.

Comment: What do you mean by `party.is"D"`? That's not proper Java code. You need to call some method on `MemeberParty` to check if it's a democrat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is fine, just add in the other 2 cases, like:

```
else if (party.is"R"){
//increment R
}
else if (party.is"I"){
//increment I
}
```

Assuming party.is"D" checks if the current MemeberParty is a D or not. Personally I'd use something like `if (MemeberParty.party.equals("D")){`

And you'll probably want to return an array

```
int[] myIntArray = {numDemocrats, numRepub, numIndep};
return myIntArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public int countObjectsOfThePassedType(Class<?> clazz, List<?> objects) {

    int counter = 0;

    for (Object obj : objects) {
        if (obj.getClass() == clazz) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

The method, when called, for example, with `Democrats.class` as first parameter, will return the number of democrats in your list.